# How to send command over SSH from iphone? Any Coding help or Sample Available?

Tags: iphone, ssh, nas

SSH is installed in NAS, Router is configured to forward the SSH port to NAS.

If anybody has done such thing before then just guide me How to send command over SSH from iphone ?
is there any code available regarding the same ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I think you need to add a bit of detail to your question. Are you trying to do this from code (in which case this is the right place). Or just ssh from your phone to NAS in which case install an SSH client (and this is not the correct forum to address that - try superuser)

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  Can I get any code for that?
After installing SSH  client what is the next step. Is there any coding help available? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install an SSH client on you iPhone, e.g. pTerm. I choose this solution for sending the occasional command to an appliance.

There is a somewhat half baked recipe on compiling libssh2 for use on the iPhone at:

http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/libssh2

Examples can be found on the libssh2 website

http://www.libssh2.org/examples/

Comment: Hi Niels, Thanks. Is there any code available to send command over SSH from iphone? Thanks in advance. Is there any sample available for guidence?

Comment: Niels just gave you a guide to compiling libssh, and some examples... and you ask him for guidance and examples...?

Comment: Thanks Niels for your response. It would help me a lot.

Comment: The libssh2 ssh2_exec.c example shows you how to execute a command remotely. It is probably a good stating point.

Comment: yes you r right Niels. Its really helpful to me. Once again Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Good luck, it sounds like a neat iPhone project!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS might help you